What 'Value' does "debug.javascript.resourceRequestOptions"expect at the end? This is showing up as an error at the end of a 'settings.json' file
I'm trying to configure my ESP-IDF Extensions in vscode and this error is at the very end of the 'settings.json'.
i've been looking it up and searching vscode and Espressif docs with no joy. I put it in a search bar and found my way here.

Somebody doesn't like this question? I was always told "There are no stupid questions." Maybe that's wrong...

The "debug.javascript.resourceRequestOptions" setting is used in Visual Studio Code's settings to configure options for fetching resources during JavaScript debugging. This setting expects an object value containing various options.
Here's an example of how you might configure this setting in your settings.json file:
{
  "debug.javascript.resourceRequestOptions": {
    "followRedirects": true,
    "headers": {
      "User-Agent": "MyCustomUserAgent"
    }
  }
}

In this example:
"followRedirects": true configures whether the debugger should follow HTTP redirects when fetching resources.
"headers" allows you to specify custom HTTP headers to include in the requests. Here, we've added a custom User-Agent header.
You can adjust these options according to your specific debugging needs. Ensure that the value you provide for "debug.javascript.resourceRequestOptions" is a valid JSON object with the appropriate options and values. If you're unsure about the available options or their values, consult the documentation for Visual Studio Code or the relevant debugging extension.
